# find matching in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
  $data['standard'][36][2] = 52.5;
  $data['standard'][42][2] = 57.5;
  $data['standard'][48][2] = 62.5;
  $data['standard'][54][2] = 67.5;
  $data['standard'][60][2] = 72.5;
  $data['standard'][36][3] = 60.5;
  $data['standard'][42][3] = 65.5;
  $data['standard'][48][3] = 70.5;
  $data['standard'][54][3] = 75.5;
  $data['standard'][60][3] = 80.5;
  $data['standard'][72][3] = 90.5;
```

i'm trying to return the keys of the third index where the first two match. e.g. for 'standard' and 48 need an array(2,3)

but for 'standard' and 72 i would return array(3)

Also I'm wondering if I should store this data in xml or something similar?

Comment: That's a weird way to structure and array.

Comment: Yea I kind of thought so too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = array_keys($data['standard'][48];
```

This just returns the keys of the `$data['standard'][48]` array: 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Sorry another question though. How do I get the 2nd index. $data['standard][][3]? Or is it more complicated?

Comment: You have to loop though the array: `foreach($data['standard'] as $second_index => $values) { var_dump($second_index, $values); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function findInArray(&$data,$param1,$param2)
{
    return isset($data[$param1][$param2]) ? array_keys($data[$param1][$param2]) : array();
}
```

Example:

```
$keys = findInArray($data,"standard",48); // array(2,3);
$keys = findInArray($data,"standard",72); // array(3);
```

It is fine to use an array for storing data, if this is easier for you to handle.